# Sample jQuery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm learning JQuery plugin and stared to create a simple plugin using below but it's not working. Please tell me what's going wrong with this. What this plugin will do is it just displays the id of the mentioned DOM element.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//creating my first JQuery plugin

JQuery.fn.myfirstplugin = function()
{
    // which returns some data

    return   this.each(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
}

</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('div').myfirstplugin();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JQuery` should be `jQuery`, it's case-sensitive.

[You can test your code with *only* that fix here](http://jsbin.com/ozobo3).